# How form class attributes work in django

Tags: python, django, forms, oop

how Form class attributes work in django ?

```
class Test(forms.Form):
    x = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print hasattr(self, 'x') #
```

return **False** ... what type of mechanism works here ?

Comment: You can try `hasattr(Test, 'x')` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried it many times.

Comment: The mechanism is that the method `__getattribute__` is overriden in forms.Form. This method is responsible for such calls. Maybe you could override it in your class as an option.

Comment: @Fomalhaut thank you. I will see how __getattribute__ works....

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to access the form fields in the `__init__` method. You should access it from the `fields` attribute. Like this:

```
class Test(forms.Form):
    x = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.fields['x']
```